# Scapy filter not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, scapy

So, right from the documentation page of scapy I copied this code:

```
a=sniff(filter="tcp and ( port 25 or port 110 )",
prn=lambda x: x.sprintf("%IP.src%:%TCP.sport% -> %IP.dst%:%TCP.dport%  %2s,TCP.flags% : %TCP.payload%"))
```

I command my Raspberry Pi to do this via the Scapy shell, however, the printed package details are not being printed WHATSOEVER! I see packages from ports 3288, ssh and other ports. However I have clearly requested to filter these packages.

This is an example of what gets printed on my screen and then deleted real fast continously!

192.168.137.178:ssh -> 192.168.137.1:3288  PA : ▒^▒▒3▒*▒▒}▒▒W+h"▒e#yR"#݌▒▒*▒▒zN!▒▒q▒▒s▒s
▒▒▒{▒[▒\▒֋▒4!▒▒̿{>▒n▒▒E▒▒▒ñ▒▒ ▒▒X8▒▒0▒▒▒▒B▒▒OM▒,T▒-W7▒ٕ▒▒▒h%▒>▒H
J▒I▒▒G5▒▒Y▒8▒ {▒%▒<Ʀ▒ٺl1f▒҄|Fe▒5H▒▒▒b▒▒▒R▒.▒OCh  Ồ▒jޠ▒c▒▒$l:▒▒▒▒?▒▒Ā▒dP̕դ{B▒^\▒?▒z|▒ Ȳ4▒▒▒h▒▒▒#4▒▒▒▒▒1F▒▒$E▒▒`?S▒C▒t▒▒4d▒(▒DT
PuTTYPuTTY192.168.137.1:3288 -> 192.168.137.178:ssh   A :
4`QZ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒;N8▒3▒▒w▒▒PE▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ꉭ▒d▒▒q▒▒1▒òYN▒!}s▒▒▒▒fvV▒▒▒/▒▒ԥS▒▒▒>K▒▒}}▒▒&T▒▒U▒b▒▒/

Comment: What OS and which version of Python/scapy are you using? The following works for me `sniff(filter="tcp and ( port 22 )", prn=lambda x: x.show())` to show only SSH related packets.

Comment: Im using Raspbian, I think im using the latest version of scapy (3.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution, my other optional packages were not installed correctly, after putting in the command:

```
sudo apt-get install tcpdump graphviz imagemagick python-gnuplot python-crypto python-pyx
```

It worked like a charm!